# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, with both classes in the same JAR!

Tags: java, classloader

My Java skills are a little rusty, but this is really weird: I am getting a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` at runtime when calling a method in a different class - note that the code compiled fine - and the other class is contained in the same JAR as the calling method!

That would seem to indicate it's not a classpath issue - but then what?

Comment: The error should tell you which method was not found. Have a look at the other class whether it actually has this method (`javap` could help here). **It could be a classpath issue**: if there is another class with same name earlier in the classpath, this one will be used before the one in the same jar.

Comment: Sounds like the classloader loaded a version of the called class that does not contain the method.

Comment: @Paulo, my classpath is remarkably clean.  @Kal, that sounds right - but where did the classloader find the older version, given that my classpath is so pristine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this article.
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3719

URL myClassURL = MyMysteryClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

That will tell you exactly where your class is being loaded from (according to the article).
Should clear up any classpath questions.

Comment: Thank you - found the culprit!  It was a rogue JAR that had been hiding away in the execution folder.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

when calling a method from one class to other class make sure that calling method name and called method name should be same and then recompile again the classes that you made changes of both method names